# Blender 3.0 files don't open/append in 2.93

Tags: import, blend-files, file-format

I've been having a problem opening and trying to append a version of blender 3.0 blends into 2.93, it just gives a file format isn't supported. I didn't realise that modifying and saving in Blender 3.0 makes the file unusable in 2.93. Is this a temporary issue or is this going to split Blender into files before and after 3.0? I really hope not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, bad news. [Release_Notes/3.0/Core](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Core)

> Forward Incompatibility Breakage: This means that loading blend
> files saved in Blender 3.0 in an older version of Blender will loose
> data (namely, inserted local modifiers, constraints etc. may be lost
> or misplaced).

Comment: In any case Blender 3 is still in final Beta so shouldn't be used to modify files from previous versions.